# Error: Uncaught (in promise): SecurityError: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History'

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I am using an MCM system that allows me to distribute web apps as packages by zipping the entire site and loading the compressed file to the MCM tool.

I tried to post my first Angular2+ router app to this tool today and received the error in the subject line.

The issue is that the service renders the app in an iframe with a different URL than the service's url.  So the service's site is app.bigtincan.com but the content is served from push.bigtincan.com//index.html

I've tried changing base href to ./ as well as {useHash: true} in the router setup and it didn't help.

Is there a way to run your Angular2+ app in an iframe?

Comment: Why the downvote???

Comment: Battling the same problem . Did you get yours working ?

Comment: unfortunately, no one has responded.  Can you up-one the question...maybe that will get it some more attention.

Comment: Well i upped it already. It was negative 1 before wasn't it?

Comment: lol, that's right!  it WAS negative!  Thanks.  And no explanation as to why someone down voted it either.

Comment: Btw i solved mine. Post your code above , i might be able to answer.